# Android Material ListView Dividers

Tags: android, listview, material-design

I am trying to build a listview that follows google's guidelines.

Here are my requirements:

1. Allow group headers
2. Allow full width dividers between groups
3. Allow partial dividers between items

Here is an image showing the header and the divider between items.
Unfortunately it's not possible to view the full width divider between the groups but that's just like a normal divider.

[image: Material listview]

I can build a custom adapter which receives subclasses of `Item`, like `HeaderItem` and `ContactItem`.

The `header.xml` would simply be

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="Today"
    android:textColor="#8A000000"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

As for the `contact.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/friend_profile_picture"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/friend_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_profile_picture"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:text="random_text"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/friend_state"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/friend_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_profile_picture"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:text="random_text"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, my problem is the item divider. The full width divider would be a normal listview divider. I'm just not sure how to do a partial dividir and make it work alongside the normal divider. Any hints?

This could also be done with `RecyclerView` and `ItemDecorator`s if it's easier/better.

Comment: Add a View/LinearLayout/RelativeLayout below "friend_state" Tetview, with black color background and left padding/margin 72dp.

Comment: Okay, but doing so, will display the line there and then the listview's divider.
Now it's only missing how to make the listview separator visible only between sections.

Comment: Ref this link, this may help you [link](http://codingdiscovery.blogspot.in/2015/02/android-listviews-with-headers.html)

Answer (score 3):

For the divider, you can have a look at the official Android *Settings* app to check out how it works. Here's the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/res/layout/dashboard_tile.xml) of a "dashboard tile":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at
          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/dashboard_tile_minimum_height">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dashboard_tile_image_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_tile_image_size"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_tile_image_margin_start"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_tile_image_margin_end" />
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:singleLine="true"
                          android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.TileTitle"
                          android:ellipsize="marquee"
                          android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/status"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_below="@id/title"
                          android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
                          android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Small"
                          android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:id="@+id/tile_divider"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="1dp"
              android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Basically, it boils down to the following:

- a `LinearLayout` in `horizontal` orientation to contain the picture and the text
- a `LinearLayout` in `vertical` orientation to hold the label and the divider

Answer (score 0):

Add a view into your RelativeLayout 
I am posting the code after adding view into your layout file

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/friend_profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friend_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_profile_picture"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="random_text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friend_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/friend_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_profile_picture"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="random_text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
     <View
    android:id="@+id/divider_line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/friend_state"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/divider_line_color"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Define the divider_line_color into colors.xml into values folder.

Even with your listview set   android:divider="@null"

Comment: Okay, but doing so, will display the line there and then the listview's divider.
I have changed your view to align with the text as I wanted, and now it's only missing how to make the listview separator visible only between sections.